# Out of memory exception while converting byte array to string [ displaying pdf on webview] +Android

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

I'm Using following code to load a pdf file on webview

```
try {
        imageByteArray =loadFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sample.pdf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    String image64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String imgTag = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + image64 + "\" />" ;
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webview.setInitialScale(30);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.loadData(imgTag, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

But getting **Outofmemory exception while converting Byte code to string**

Question :

1.How can i load large byte code to a string type
2.Or can i use other data type to display byte array in webview
See in this line
`"<imgsrc=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + image64 + "\" />"` i have to give string image64 . Or is there any alternatives available ?